# How to get the ip address of eth0 wlan0 of a host from docker container

Tags: docker, networking

I have a docker container running on the host. If I do `ip addr show` it gives the ip address assigned to the container. This ip address is the ip address which docker creates for its virtual network.

The host which I have has `wlan0` `eth0`. Is there any way I can get the ip address of `wlan0` or `eth0` of the host.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to change network mode to "host".

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings

Comment: I world rather build the container with some environment variables with this info, or `docker run -e HOST_WLAN0=1.2.3.4...`

Comment: @user2915097 By using `docker run -e HOST_WLAN0=1.2.3.4...` will I be able to get the ip address of wlan0 in container.?

Comment: The idea behind docker is to isolate the container from the host. So the container should not be able to connect inside the host. So either you have in the Dockerfile used to build the image something like `ENV HOST_WLAN0 1.2.3.4` or at run time you provide this info. But the container should not be able to get this information from the host, you need to give it to the container, either ay build time (ENV) or at run time (-e)

Comment: >>>By using docker run -e HOST_WLAN0=1.2.3.4... will I be able to get the ip address of wlan0 in container.? Yes, it will be in $HOST_WLAN0 environment variable.

Comment: If your host is Linux, then you can try: docker run -e HOST_WLAN0=`ip addr` ... and in container, you can parse $HOST_WLAN0.

Comment: @user2915097 This is good but if the host has DHCP enabled so the IP address might get change some time. Will it also reflect the same (changed ip ) in the container.?

Comment: Sure, but at run time it should not change

Comment: @user2915097 By run time do you mean when we run the docker using `docker run..` command. I am actually including this in `Dockerfile`, so will it get reflected in container when included in Dockerfile.?

Comment: @user2915097 No it dont reflect the new ip address in case of dhcp.